# resteasy : How to consume Map as QueryParam in resteasy service api

Tags: java, json, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

Hi I am using resteasy api, I need to use Map as QueryParam. I can use list as QueryParam but when I try to pass Map I get the error mentioned below.

Here is my service code

```
@GET
@Path("/movies")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public SolrDocumentList getPropertiesByKeyword1(@QueryParam("filterMap") final Map<String,String> list)
 {}
```

[org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (http-/0.0.0.0:18080-1) Failed executing POST /solr/search/properties: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [map type; class java.util.LinkedHashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.String]] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: com.rentr.solr.SearchRequestDto["filterMap"])
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:183) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:88) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:111) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:280) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:234) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:221) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]

**Can we use Map as QueryParam, If yes then how?**

Answer (score 2):

The injected value will not be a `Map`. With a `Map`, you are suggesting that there will be different keys, when in actuality, there is only one, `"filter"`. So instead of a `Map`, you use a `List<String>`

```
@Path("list")
public class QueryParamMapResource {

    @GET
    public Response getQueryParams(@QueryParam("filter") List<String> params) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Filter Params: ");
        for (String value : params) {
            builder.append(value).append(",");
        }
        return Response.ok(builder.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

> `C:\>curl "http://localhost:8080/test/rest/list?filter=hello&filter=world"` 
>   **Result:** `Filter Params: hello,world,`

---

Another alternative, is to get all the query params from the `UriInfo` (seems unnecessary, just showing you options :-)

```
@GET
public Response getQueryParams(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryMap = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Filter Params: ");
    List<String> params = queryMap.get("filter");
    for (String value : params) {
        builder.append(value).append(",");
    }
    return Response.ok(builder.toString()).build();
}
```

From the `queryMap`, you can attempt to get an query parameter values by key, and it will return a list of the values for that key

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but as per your proposed solution, by using list we can use only values but I need key and value pair. Like if I want to fetch movie list by using filterMap then my map might be like.
year:2010
actor:Daniel
movieType:Action

Comment: The thing is, query parameters can be duplicated, meaning a key can have more than one value. So the values need to be kept in a list. If you only want the value(s) for one key, the inject the list with the `@QueryParam` using the name of the key. Otherwise if you want all query params (all keys), then use the `UriInfo` and get the query map. Then you can get them all by key name

Comment: Anything other than that,  maybe you need to give an example of what the actual query/url will look like